# Combining all paths with the same fill color into a group?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator CS5 is there a way to combine all the paths with the same color into the same group?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Select one of the objects and in the main menu go to `Select > Same > Fill Color`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on Mac to group the selected objects.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Alexei's answer..

If objects are on the same layer, you can also select the paths and use `Pathfinder > Merge`. This will combine all shapes with the same color.

If the object are touching, the Merge command will combine the objects into one object.